# Magento: The 'community' channel is not installed

Tags: magento

I was trying to install a made-by-myself extension, but it return this error:

```
CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.
```

I had my friend install the extension on her magento and it worked, so the problem must come from my magento. How to resolve this? Please note that my magento is installed on window localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following command via SSH on Magento root:

```
./mage mage-setup
```

Comment: But... but my magento is installed on window localhost :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use from your terminal or shell scripting:
chmod -R mage
./mage mage-setup

Ensure you are in the right location while giving permission as well as before installing clear cache and refresh magento connect
strong text